# Use 'parse' in Red language with number block

Tags: red

I imitate the follow code that comes from Helpin'Red

```
a: "big black cat"
parse a [ to "black" insert "FAT "]
print a
big FAT black cat
```

with mine:

```
b: [1 2 3]
parse b [to 2 insert 4]
print b
4 4 1 2 3 ;; but what I mean is "1 4 2 3".
```

What's wrong with my code? And how to get the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `to` matches the input up to a specified rule until it succeeds or the end is reached.
2. `2` matches a specified number of times.
3. `insert 4` inserts a value at the current position, and always succeeds.

   1. Which means that `2 insert 4` inserts two `4`'s and succeeds.
   2. `to` "advances" the input up to a matched `2 insert 4`: I say "advances" because it really doesn't, insertion happens at the head.

To achieve what you want you need to escape `2` using `quote`:

```
>> also block: [1 2 3] parse block [to quote 2 insert 4]
== [1 4 2 3]
```

FYI, Parse has official [reference documentation](https://github.com/red/docs/blob/master/en/parse.adoc).

Comment: Many thanks for  your solution and the reference to `parse`!